# Apache Mysql PHP5 ubuntu home server configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, ip-forwarding

Here is my problem i have been searching for days now and i didn't found something i can apply directly. i have apache and Mysql and php and i am using ubuntu.

I have a static IP, but i am not in control with the router itself. So what i need is to publish my website from home using the combination i mentioned above.

i dont care about security issues because it will be just for selected people for a while not for a long time?

Comment: So what is the question? You have the address and the software. Are you asking how to set up those things or a question about the networking?

Comment: Yes I am asking how to setup or is there any tutorial I can refere to ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a port forward in the router to your ubuntu server - otherwise it just wont work unless you sit on the same LAN as the server.